# Translation animation being ignored until second tap

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, core-animation, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the following code that runs whenever a tap gesture is recognised. It moves a UIImageView to the tap location and also rotates the UIImageView.

However, the translation animation never runs on the first tap. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap{

    CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.view];



    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                          delay:0
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         self.icon.center = point;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //
                     }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                          delay:0
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         self.icon.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //
                     }];

}
```

Comment: Why are you using two animation blocks ? You can put the translation and the rotation instructions in the same one !

Comment: @urimoai i found some thing i posted refer this... i hope this will you ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you need code like this...

in the .h file u declare one `CGAffineTransform` variable say `initial`....

in `viewDidLoad` you need to store the initial transform value by this...

```
initial=self.icon.transform;
```

then you need to change your method to this type...

```
   -(void) onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap{

        CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.view];



        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                              delay:0
                            options:0
                         animations:^{
                             self.icon.center = point;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             //
                         }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                              delay:0
                            options:0
                         animations:^{

if (self.icon.transform.a  == initial.a) 
                         {
                             self.icon.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             self.icon.transform = initial;
                         }


                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             //
                         }];

    }
```

this is an idea you need to implement your logic with it....